# How can I copy multiple partitions on several drives (/dev/sdXY) to an external drive?

Tags: command-line, backup, external-hdd

I need to copy all the partitions from all hard drives to an external hard drive.

Preferably I'd like to do this in a way that I will be able to use files later, i.e not in a single image file or so.

How do I do so with terminal commands?

Comment: did you mean,you want to backup from your files?

Comment: yes. I want to backup all files from all hard drives on my dual boot computer (ubuntu, windows)

Comment: FWIW you can back up files as a disk image because you can then mount that image on the loopback device (eg `mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt -o loop` [which is in the man page]) and access the files as if the image were an ordinary disk.

Comment: @pbhj  jush show OP how it's done in an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 cd /
 tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

Explanation:

`c` - create a new backup archive.
`v` - verbose mode, tar will print what it's doing to the screen.
`p` - preserves the permissions of the files put in the archive for restoration later.
`z` - compress the backup file with 'gzip' to make it smaller.
`f`  - specifies where to store the backup.
`--exclude=/example/path` - The options following this model instruct tar what directories NOT to backup. We don't want to backup everything since some directories aren't very useful to include. The first exclusion rule directs tar not to back itself up, this is important to avoid errors during the operation.
`--one-file-system` - Do not include files on a different filesystem.

If you want other filesystems, such as a `/home` partition, or external media mounted in `/media` backed up, you either need to back them up separately, or omit this flag. If you do omit this flag, you will need to add several more `--exclude=` arguments to avoid filesystems you do not want. These would be `/proc`, `/sy`s, `/mnt`, `/media`, `/run` and `/dev` directories in root. `/proc` and `/sys` are virtual filesystems that provide windows into variables of the running kernel, so you do not want to try and backup or restore them. `/dev` is a `tmpfs` whose contents are created and deleted dynamically by `udev`, so you also do not want to backup or restore it. Likewise, `/run` is a `tmpfs` that holds variables about the running system that do not need to be backed up.